# Как записать стихотворный текст “лесенкой” (по одному слову в строке)?

Tags: c++, c, массивы

**Задание:**

Стихотворный текст (в строке не более 80 символов) имеет четырех строчные строку. Записать его “лесенкой” (по одному слову в строке), вставляя пустую строку после каждого четверостишия.

**Мой код:**

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "conio.h"

using namespace std;

size_t LengthOfUtf8String(const std::string &utf8_string) {
  return distance(utf8_string.begin(), utf8_string.end());
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  char sub;
  int i = 0, n = 0;
  string a[80];
  string s;

  system("CLS");
  cout << "Input str" << endl;
  cin >> s;

  do {
    i += 1;
    if ((s[i] == ' ') || (s[i] == ',')) {
      n += 1;
      a[n] = sub;
      sub = ' ';
    }
    else sub = sub + s[i];
  } while (!(i == LengthOfUtf8String(s)));
  n += 1;
  a[n] = sub;
  cout << endl;


  for (i = 1; i <= n; i++)
  {
    if (i % 4 == 1)  cout << a[i] << endl;
    if (i % 4 == 2)  cout << ' ' << a[i] << endl;
    if (i % 4 == 3)  cout << "   " << a[i] << endl;
    if (i % 4 == 0) {
      cout << "    " << a[i] << endl;
      cout << endl;

    }
  }
  system("pause");
}
```

**Вопрос: что я сделал не так? И как это нужно сделать правильно?**

Comment: С первых строк кода сразу же вопрос. Чем не устроил [`std::string::size()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/size/)? Зачем эти приседания с `distance`?

Comment: Проблемы с UTF-8 были...

Comment: То есть вы утверждаете, что `size` и `distance` дают разные результаты? А можно посмотреть на это? Или это просто так осталось, и проблем уже нет?

Comment: Это уже осталось и проблемы с этим нет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если текст вводится исключительно пользователем и результат выводится исключительно на экран, то можно сделать так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(){
    std::string word;
    for(int counter = 0; std::cin >> word; ++counter){
        int pad = counter % 4;

        output << std::string(pad, ' ') << word << "\n";

        if(pad == 3){
            output << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Если русским языком, читаем по одному слову и вставляем отступ перед каждым последующим.

Если вдруг строку надо обязательно прочитать, и результат обязательно сохранить в строку перед выводом, то можно все это дело немного обобщить:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string toLadder(const std::string &str){
    std::stringstream input(str);
    std::stringstream output;

    std::string word;
    for(int counter = 0; input >> word; ++counter){
        int pad = counter % 4;

        output << std::string(pad, ' ') << word << "\n";

        if(pad == 3){
            output << "\n";
        }
    }

    return output.str();
}

int main(){
    std::string line;
    std::getline(std::cin, line);

    std::cout << toLadder(line);
}
```

[Пример](http://cpp.sh/2x2aa)

Comment: `вставляя пустую строку после каждого четверостишия` Эту часть задания вы забили, ну и на этом спасибо)

Comment: @MiT, я заметил) Надеялся успеть исправить ответ прежде чем кто-то заметит. Сейчас есть пустые строки

Comment: Я вас понял) Спасибо)